# Recursion with re.sub()

Tags: python, regex

If we use it as follows:

```
re.sub("a\(\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*\)", "100", "a(440, 330)"
```

we get:

```
>> "100"
```

Now, for example we have `a()` inside of `a()`:

```
re.sub("a\(\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*\)", "100", "a(30, a(30,30))")
```

we get:

```
>> 'a(30, 100)'
```

But I want something like this:

```
1. a(30, a(30,30)) # replace the nested 'a' 
2. a(30, 100) # now work with the remainder
3. '100' # final string
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You could do the replacements in a loop until nothing changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep replacing until there's nothing left to replace:

```
while True:
    output = re.sub("a\(\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*\)", "100", input)
    if output == input:
        break
    input = output
```

Comment: I was just about to write this up, pursuant to your comment.! Glad you beat me to it :)

Comment: Upvoting this compact solution. Been enjoying a cruise through your regex answers... Nice work! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without the while loop using '+' option which stand for multiple match.

```
re.sub("[a\(\s*\d*\s*,\s*\d*\s*\)]+", "100", "a(30, a(30,30))")
```

I too tend to forget the regex option which some time does not strike you right away. Make a list/print & keep it front of you. Invariably you will end up noticing/remembering all the option possible for match case over time

Comment: Thanks! Much better than the while loop.

Comment: I just found this answer and I can let it without a further comment.
Your pattern is matching any sequence of characters included between square brackets, so this isn't a recursive replace.

All characters included in "a(30, a(30,30))" are matching this list of characters, so they end up being replaced by 100. Something like "aaa1234()()()" would be replaced by "100" too.